# API with a PUT request in Modelviewset which has not null values

Tags: api, django-rest-framework, python-requests, put

When calling a API with a PUT request, I get a message saying that the fields name and name_abbrev are mandatory:

What are way in which I can carryout put operation without supplying 'name' and 'name_abbrev' in the API payload

I was trying to carryout put operation without supplying 'name' and 'name_abbrev' in the API Put REQUEST payload but I was not successfull

Answer (score 0):

you can either provide a `required=False` in mentioned serializer fields

---

OR

pass `partial=True` within the serializer itself, called from the corresponding view function

Answer (score 0):

Setting `kwargs['partial'] = True`, in `update` function helped.